# Apresentar uma caixa de texto formatada para preenchimento

Tags: visual-basic-6

Bom dia
Senhores, pesquisei na internet inteira mas acho que não soube me expressar por isso venho lhes perguntar…
tenho um comando VB para alterar o ip do win7 mas gostaria que o comando perguntasse qual ip eu gostaria de colocar segue comando…

```
' ## Script para alterer ip da Placa de Rede ##

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\.\root\cimv2")
Set colNetAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled=TRUE")

strIPAddress = Array("10.10.0.7") 'Coloque o IP fixo
strSubnetMask = Array("255.255.255.0") 'Coloque a Mascara de SubNet

strGateway = Array("10.1.1.1") 'Coloque o Gateway
strGatewayMetric = Array(1)

strDNS = Array("200.204.0.10","200.204.0.138") 'Coloque o IP DNS

For Each objNetAdapter in colNetAdapters
    errEnable = objNetAdapter.EnableStatic(strIPAddress, strSubnetMask)
    errGateways = objNetAdapter.SetGateways(strGateway, strGatewaymetric)
    objNetAdapter.SetDNSServerSearchOrder strDNS
Next
```

Na parte `strIPAddress = Array("10.10.0.7") 'Coloque o IP fixo` gostaria que abrisse uma caixa de texto pra o usuário alterar o final ou se não for possível o ip inteiro, por exemplo:

```
10.10.0.___
```

Comment: Para apresentar uma caixa de texto personalizada vc pode usar o componente "Microsoft Maked Edit Control", com ela é possível criar mascaras para o texto.

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais simples é utilizando um inputbox. Exemplo:

```
ip = InputBox("Coloque o IP fixo", "Mudar IP")
```

Uma outra forma mais trabalhosa mas que traria resultados estéticos melhores seria fazer um form e chamar ele retornando o resultado pra sua variavel.

Comment: strIPAddress = Array InputBox("Frase de descricao", "Titulo da box") 'Coloque o IP fixo

Comment: deste jeito nao entendi muito bem?

Comment: alterei para ficar mais claro

Comment: Bom se eu entendi ficaria assim

Comment: strIPAddress = InputBox("Coloque o IP fixo", "Mudar IP")

Comment: vou ser sincero nao eh minha praia vbs

Comment: sim, é isso, a caixa de texto irá aparecer com o titulo mudar ip e uma descrição escrito coloque o ip fixo junto de um input e os botões ok e cancelar